# Can't install perl package Games::Irrlicht - fatal error

Tags: perl, perl-module, cpan

I'm trying to install the CPAN module [`Games::Irrlicht`](https://metacpan.org/pod/distribution/Games-Irrlicht/lib/Games/Irrlicht.pm) to deal with graphics. Some file isn't getting downloaded properly or something, resulting in a fatal error.

What's wrong?

My terminal output:

```
cpan[1]> install Games::Irrlicht
Reading '/home/me/.cpan/Metadata'
  Database was generated on Sat, 05 Mar 2016 02:17:02 GMT
Running install for module 'Games::Irrlicht'
Checksum for /home/me/.cpan/sources/authors/id/T/TE/TELS/games/Games-Irrlicht-0.04.tar.gz ok
Scanning cache /home/me/.cpan/build for sizes
............................................................................DONE
'YAML' not installed, will not store persistent state
Configuring T/TE/TELS/games/Games-Irrlicht-0.04.tar.gz with Makefile.PL
Checking if your kit is complete...
Looks good
Warning: prerequisite Config::Simple 4.55 not found.
Warning (mostly harmless): No library found for -lIrrlicht
Generating a Unix-style Makefile
Writing Makefile for Games::Irrlicht
Writing MYMETA.yml and MYMETA.json
  TELS/games/Games-Irrlicht-0.04.tar.gz
  /usr/bin/perl Makefile.PL INSTALLDIRS=site -- OK
Running make for T/TE/TELS/games/Games-Irrlicht-0.04.tar.gz
---- Unsatisfied dependencies detected during ----
----   TELS/games/Games-Irrlicht-0.04.tar.gz  ----
    Config::Simple [requires]
Running install for module 'Config::Simple'
Checksum for /home/me/.cpan/sources/authors/id/S/SH/SHERZODR/Config-Simple-4.58.tar.gz ok
Configuring S/SH/SHERZODR/Config-Simple-4.58.tar.gz with Makefile.PL
Checking if your kit is complete...
Looks good
Generating a Unix-style Makefile
Writing Makefile for Config::Simple
Writing MYMETA.yml and MYMETA.json
  SHERZODR/Config-Simple-4.58.tar.gz
  /usr/bin/perl Makefile.PL INSTALLDIRS=site -- OK
Running make for S/SH/SHERZODR/Config-Simple-4.58.tar.gz
cp Simple.pm blib/lib/Config/Simple.pm
AutoSplitting blib/lib/Config/Simple.pm (blib/lib/auto/Config/Simple)
Manifying blib/man3/Config::Simple.3pm
  SHERZODR/Config-Simple-4.58.tar.gz
  /usr/bin/make -- OK
Running make test
PERL_DL_NONLAZY=1 /usr/bin/perl "-MExtUtils::Command::MM" "-MTest::Harness" "-e" "undef *Test::Harness::Switches; test_harness(0, 'blib/lib', 'blib/arch')" t/*.t
t/bug.t ............. ok     
t/create.t .......... ok     
t/import.t .......... ok   
t/ini.t ............. ok     
t/is_modified.t ..... ok   
t/read-rv.t ......... ok   
t/simple.t .......... ok   
t/simplified-ini.t .. ok   
t/tie.t ............. ok   
All tests successful.
Files=9, Tests=75,  1 wallclock secs ( 0.06 usr  0.00 sys +  0.24 cusr  0.04 csys =  0.34 CPU)
Result: PASS
  SHERZODR/Config-Simple-4.58.tar.gz
  /usr/bin/make test -- OK
Running make install
Installing /usr/local/share/perl/5.20.2/auto/Config/Simple/import_from.al
Installing /usr/local/share/perl/5.20.2/auto/Config/Simple/EXISTS.al
Installing /usr/local/share/perl/5.20.2/auto/Config/Simple/TIEHASH.al
Installing /usr/local/share/perl/5.20.2/auto/Config/Simple/NEXTKEY.al
Installing /usr/local/share/perl/5.20.2/auto/Config/Simple/hashref.al
Installing /usr/local/share/perl/5.20.2/auto/Config/Simple/CLEAR.al
Installing /usr/local/share/perl/5.20.2/auto/Config/Simple/FIRSTKEY.al
Installing /usr/local/share/perl/5.20.2/auto/Config/Simple/verbose.al
Installing /usr/local/share/perl/5.20.2/auto/Config/Simple/param_hash.al
Installing /usr/local/share/perl/5.20.2/auto/Config/Simple/block.al
Installing /usr/local/share/perl/5.20.2/auto/Config/Simple/vars.al
Installing /usr/local/share/perl/5.20.2/auto/Config/Simple/autosplit.ix
Installing /usr/local/share/perl/5.20.2/auto/Config/Simple/errstr.al
Installing /usr/local/share/perl/5.20.2/auto/Config/Simple/dump.al
Installing /usr/local/share/perl/5.20.2/auto/Config/Simple/import_names.al
Installing /usr/local/share/perl/5.20.2/auto/Config/Simple/DELETE.al
Installing /usr/local/share/perl/5.20.2/auto/Config/Simple/FETCH.al
Installing /usr/local/share/perl/5.20.2/auto/Config/Simple/write_string.al
Installing /usr/local/share/perl/5.20.2/auto/Config/Simple/STORE.al
Installing /usr/local/share/perl/5.20.2/auto/Config/Simple/error.al
Installing /usr/local/share/perl/5.20.2/Config/Simple.pm
Installing /usr/local/man/man3/Config::Simple.3pm
Appending installation info to /usr/local/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/perl/5.20.2/perllocal.pod
  SHERZODR/Config-Simple-4.58.tar.gz
  /usr/bin/make install  -- OK
  TELS/games/Games-Irrlicht-0.04.tar.gz
  Has already been unwrapped into directory /home/me/.cpan/build/Games-Irrlicht-0.04-7adKre
  TELS/games/Games-Irrlicht-0.04.tar.gz
  Has already been prepared
Running make for T/TE/TELS/games/Games-Irrlicht-0.04.tar.gz
cp lib/Games/Irrlicht/Group.pm blib/lib/Games/Irrlicht/Group.pm
cp lib/Games/Irrlicht/EventHandler.pm blib/lib/Games/Irrlicht/EventHandler.pm
cp lib/Games/Irrlicht/Constants.pm blib/lib/Games/Irrlicht/Constants.pm
cp lib/Games/Irrlicht/Timer.pm blib/lib/Games/Irrlicht/Timer.pm
cp lib/Games/Irrlicht/Thingy.pm blib/lib/Games/Irrlicht/Thingy.pm
cp lib/Games/Irrlicht.pm blib/lib/Games/Irrlicht.pm
Running Mkbootstrap for Games::Irrlicht ()
chmod 644 Irrlicht.bs
/usr/bin/perl /usr/share/perl/5.20/ExtUtils/xsubpp  -C++ -typemap /usr/share/perl/5.20/ExtUtils/typemap  Irrlicht.xs > Irrlicht.xsc && mv Irrlicht.xsc Irrlicht.c
Warning: Found a 'CODE' section which seems to be using 'RETVAL' but no 'OUTPUT' section. in Irrlicht.xs, line 458
g++ -c   -D_REENTRANT -D_GNU_SOURCE -DDEBIAN -fwrapv -fno-strict-aliasing -pipe -I/usr/local/include -D_LARGEFILE_SOURCE -D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64 -O2   -DVERSION=\"0.04\" -DXS_VERSION=\"0.04\" -fPIC "-I/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/perl/5.20/CORE"   Irrlicht.c
Irrlicht.xs:6:31: fatal error: Irrlicht/irrlicht.h: No such file or directory
compilation terminated.
Makefile:362: recipe for target 'Irrlicht.o' failed
make: *** [Irrlicht.o] Error 1
  TELS/games/Games-Irrlicht-0.04.tar.gz
  /usr/bin/make -- NOT OK
Failed during this command:
 TELS/games/Games-Irrlicht-0.04.tar.gz        : make NO
```

This is in a terminal in Ubuntu 15.10

The [README](https://metacpan.org/pod/distribution/Games-Irrlicht/README#DEPENDENCIES) says to put "precompiled files" and "header files" into specific directories, but I can't find those files.

Answer (score 3):

[The README file](https://metacpan.org/pod/distribution/Games-Irrlicht/README#DEPENDENCIES) says

> You need to install the Irrlicht engine from http://irrlicht.sf.net

It looks from your log like you haven't done that

You should also read the rest of the `README` as there are a few other places where things may go wrong

Comment: What precompiled files? What header files?

Comment: There are no .a files in the downloaded zipfile.  running make in one of the irrlicht folders generates 'libIrrlicht.a' but the other two mentioned are evasive, and it's very unclear which header files it's talking about.  There is no irrlicht.h in the directory.

Comment: @Menasheh: I have answered your question. If you don't know how to install the *Irrlicht* engine then that is another question altogether.